# Oracle - Frequently accessed tables

Tags: oracle

We're running Oracle 12c SE.  I've read a lot of postings that say v$segment_statistics may have information on which are the most frequently queried or updated objects.  However, can that be broken down?   Say that one might want to see during what times of the day certain objects are hotter than other objects, or perhaps number of physical reads or writes per hour for a given table?

Does Oracle SE offer this an any of the v$ views?

Comment: All of the data dictionary views (including the v$ views) are fully documented in the database [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/toc.htm).     My question is . . .  what would you do with that information once you have it?  What actual problem do you hope to solve?  Beware of contracting a case of [Compulsive Tuning Disorder](https://oracle-base.com/blog/2009/05/29/compulsive-tuning-disorder/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing [`dba_hist_seg_stat`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_4031.htm) which is one of the tables that is populated as part of the Automatic Workload Repository (AWR).  If you're on the standard edition, I don't believe querying these views would violate your license agreement but I don't keep up to date with changes to licensing terms particularly for the standard edition.

You could replicate this functionality yourself by putting together a job that runs every few minutes, queries `v$segment_statistics`, and writes the delta from the prior snap to a custom table.  You could then query that table to see what activity was going on at different points in time.

Comment: Question on this:   So, if I take a snapshot or the values I'm interested in, and then do it again in say 5 minutes, and calc the different, does that basically tell me how many reads were done on that table in 5 minutes?    Do the counts ever get cleared or reset, or are they just ever growing?

Comment: @LandonStatis - The `v$` views will reset when you restart the instance.  I haven't tested what happens if, say, you rename a segment.  But 99% of the time, yes, if you look at the delta between two snapshots, you can see the change in any of the statistics for that period of time.